# Create purchase order in zoho books via API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zoho, zohobooks

I am using the Zoho Books API to create a purchase order

(https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/#Purchase-Order_Create_a_purchase_order) -

The only required items appear to be `vendor_id` and `line_items`.  However, after creating a job I am getting following message:

`ZohoBooks::BadRequestError: Purchase order cannot be created for a non-purchase item.`

And here is the code:

```

```
class CreatePurchaseOrderJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(order_id)
    @order = SupplierOrder.find(order_id)
    create_purchase_order
  end

  private

  attr_reader :order

  def vendor
    name = order.supplier.name
    books.get_contact_with_options(contact_type: :vendor, contact_name: name)
  end

  def create_purchase_order
    payload = {
      vendor_id: vendor['contact_id'],
      purchaseorder_number: order.reference,
      reference_number: order.reference,
      line_items: line_items
    }

    books.create_purchase_order(payload)
  end

  def line_items
    order.rfq_line_item_prices.order(:id).map do |price|
      line_item(price)
    end
  end

  def line_item(price)
    {
      name: price.current_line_item.shape,
      description: price.current_line_item&.name,
      bcy_rate: price.unit_price.to_f,
      rate: price.unit_price.to_f,
      quantity: price.current_line_item.quantity,
      tax_id: Registry.zoho_vat_tax_id,
      item_custom_fields: [
        { label: 'Grade', value: price.current_line_item&.grade },
        { label: 'Finish', value: price.current_line_item&.finish },
        { label: 'Dimensions', value: price.current_line_item&.dimensions }
      ]
    }
  end

  def books
    @books ||= Registry.books
  end
end
```

This is the same code we use to make invoices and that works, so I'm missing something magical that let's Zoho know this is a purchase item, without any indication to what that may be.  I asked via chat and got the following:  `The reason why you're getting this error message is because, You can create a purchase order only when you add the purchase info for an item.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer turned out to be easier than I thought, although it took longer than I would have liked to uncover.  Eventually I decided try adding attributes even if they were defined as optional.  By including the item id it allowed the purchase order to be created.

My final code:

```
class CreatePurchaseOrderJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(order_id)
    @order = SupplierOrder.find(order_id)
    create_purchase_order
  end

  private

  def payload
    {
      vendor_id: vendor['contact_id'],
      reference_number: order&.reference,
      line_items: line_items
    }
  end

  attr_reader :order

  def vendor
    @vendor ||= books.find_or_create_vendor(order.supplier)
  end

  def create_purchase_order
    begin
      books.create_purchase_order(payload)
    rescue Exception => e
      Airbrake.notify(e)
    end
  end

  def line_items
    order.line_item_prices.order(:id).map do |price|
      line_item(price)
    end
  end

  def item_id(name)
    books.find_or_create_item(name)['item_id']
  end

  def line_item(price)
    {
      item_id: item_id(price.current_line_item.shape),
      description: price.current_line_item&.description,
      bcy_rate: price.unit_price.to_f,
      rate: price.unit_price.to_f,
      quantity: price.current_line_item.quantity,
      tax_id: Registry.vat_tax_id,
      item_custom_fields: [
        { label: 'Grade', value: price.current_line_item&.grade },
        { label: 'Finish', value: price.current_line_item&.finish },
        { label: 'Dimensions', value: price.current_line_item&.dimensions }
      ]
    }
  end

  def books
    @books ||= Registry.books
  end
end
```